# Cannot Create Database PHP

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I am beginning  to create my own Interface to use with MySql though I cannot seem to create a database with the code I have at the bottom. Everything else works also i can echo out the $ObtainDatabase variable to see that it does have a value stored. Any suggestions would be great.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    //define connection
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'over_watch','XXXXXXx','billing');

    //Variables
    $UserEmail = $_SESSION['email'];
    $MysqlUserDataBaseCreate  = $_POST['create_database'];

    //CheckIfUserExists
    $SeeIfUserExist = $conn->prepare("SELECT (email) FROM database_users WHERE email= ?;");
    $SeeIfUserExist->bind_param('s',$UserEmail);
    $SeeIfUserExist->execute();

     $SeeIfUserExist->bind_result($ObtainedEmail);
     $SeeIfUserExist->store_result();
     $SeeIfUserExist->fetch();
     $RowsReturnedFromPreparedStatment = $SeeIfUserExist->num_rows();


    if($RowsReturnedFromPreparedStatment < 1){
      $InsertIntoDatabase = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO database_users(email,check_if_created) VALUES(?,?);");
      $InsertIntoDatabase->bind_param('ss',$UserEmail,$MysqlUserDataBaseCreate);
      $InsertIntoDatabase->execute();

      $SelectDatabaseToCreate = $conn->prepare(" SELECT (check_if_created) FROM database_users WHERE email = ?;");
      $SelectDatabaseToCreate->bind_param('s', $UserEmail);
      $SelectDatabaseToCreate->execute();

      $SelectDatabaseToCreate->bind_result($ObtainDatabase);
      $SelectDatabaseToCreate->fetch();
      $CreateDatabase = "CREATE DATABASE $ObtainDatabase ;";
      $conn->query($CreateDatabase);

    }else{
      echo 'user permitted to one database';
    }


    ?>
```

Comment: am i missing where `$ObtainDatabase` is defined?

Comment: I remember seeing this post a while ago. What happened to that? Also, in relation to your question add error reporting so that you'll know what's wrong with your code.

Comment: @smith I am selecting it from the data base via prepare statement (check_if_created) and then obtaining the value by using bind_result() and fetch().

Comment: Please print the output you are getting when you echo $ObtainDatabase. We need to see the create table statement in order to determine why it isn't working.

Comment: @SeanW333 the $ObtainDatabase variable is essentially the $MysqlUserDataBaseCreate  variable defined at the top of the code . I changed the variable name after I used the prepared statements bind result function.

Comment: Okay, but I need to see the full text of that statement to have any hope of evaluating it for problems (e.g., `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS your_table (column1 datatype, column2 datatype);` , etc.). All I'm seeing right now is `CREATE DATABASE $ObtainDatabase` which doesn't tell me anything about the table or how you are creating it.

Comment: Also, if you wrap your data functions with try/catch statements, you can get whatever errors may be returned from the database. More info on that here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: I am using PhpMyAdmin for any table creation, the interface is only Suppsose to allow a database to be created and users to be created for the database(in another script)... I have no php script to create a table for this database... My problem is that the database is not being created.

Comment: @jim. Can you print $CreateDatabase variable once to check what query is being executed ?

Comment: @Sudharshan Nair not sure what you mean by what query is being executed. The query is suppose to create the Database. With the value stored in the $ObtainDatabase variable.

Comment: @jim. Just after `$CreateDatabase = "CREATE DATABASE $ObtainDatabase ;";` add `print_r($CreateDatabase);exit;` to see whether the statement is correct or not

Comment: @Sudharshan Nair If i print that I get fooCREATE DATABASE foo;... foo being the database name stored in the $ObtainDatabase variable.

Comment: @jim. Why is this foo appending before CREATE ?

Comment: @Sudharshan Nair that is because i had another echo variable defined more recent in the code that i forgot to delete.

Comment: @Sudharshan Nair the problem is lying in the $conn->query()

Comment: @jim. Can you try this `if (!$conn->query($CreateDatabase)) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
}`

Comment: @Sudharshan Nair Errormessage: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: @jim. I have added my answer with Code, Can you try that ?

Comment: @Sudharshan Nair It works thanks for the help it is appreciated.

Comment: @jim. Welcome. Please upvote and approve if its useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this Code.

Details about this error can be found in the mysql docs. Reading those details makes it clear that the result sets of a prepared statement execution need to be fetched completely before executing another prepared statement on the same connection.

Here is the doc where you can [refer](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php)

```
<?php
    session_start();

    //define connection
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'over_watch','XXXXXXx','billing');

    //Variables
    $UserEmail = $_SESSION['email'];
    $MysqlUserDataBaseCreate  = $_POST['create_database'];

    //CheckIfUserExists
    $SeeIfUserExist = $conn->prepare("SELECT (email) FROM database_users WHERE email= ?;");
    $SeeIfUserExist->bind_param('s',$UserEmail);
    $SeeIfUserExist->execute();
    $SeeIfUserExist->store_result();

     $SeeIfUserExist->bind_result($ObtainedEmail);
     $SeeIfUserExist->store_result();
     $SeeIfUserExist->fetch();
     $RowsReturnedFromPreparedStatment = $SeeIfUserExist->num_rows();


    if($RowsReturnedFromPreparedStatment < 1){
      $InsertIntoDatabase = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO database_users(email,check_if_created) VALUES(?,?);");
      $InsertIntoDatabase->bind_param('ss',$UserEmail,$MysqlUserDataBaseCreate);
      $InsertIntoDatabase->execute();
      $InsertIntoDatabase->store_result();

      $SelectDatabaseToCreate = $conn->prepare(" SELECT (check_if_created) FROM database_users WHERE email = ?;");
      $SelectDatabaseToCreate->bind_param('s', $UserEmail);
      $SelectDatabaseToCreate->execute();
      $SelectDatabaseToCreate->store_result();

      $SelectDatabaseToCreate->bind_result($ObtainDatabase);
      $SelectDatabaseToCreate->fetch();
      $CreateDatabase = "CREATE DATABASE $ObtainDatabase ;";
      $conn->query($CreateDatabase);

    }else{
      echo 'user permitted to one database';
    }


    ?>
```

Comment: Yes  Thank you!! this works would you mind sharing your insight with me???

Comment: @jim. I have given a link, You can refer that for more information